# How to fix undefined method in nested models? post/create in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Beginner programmer, probably getting over my head with multiple models, but your help would be greatly appreciated.  Subjects have many pages, pages have many sections, sections have section edits.  Been searching for hours for solution, just haven't found anything that works.  Why am I getting this error?  I've clearly overlooked something... Thanks!

Error:

```
NoMethodError in SectionsController#create
NoMethodError (undefined method `subject_id' for #<Section:0x007fe2efe24a80>
Did you mean?  object_id):
app/controllers/sections_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

sections_controller.rb

```
class SectionsController < ApplicationController

 layout 'admin'

 before_action :confirm_logged_in
 before_action :find_page
 before_action :find_pages, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
 before_action :set_section_count, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
 ...

def create
  @section = Section.new(section_params)
  @section.page = @page
  if @section.save
    flash[:notice] = "Section created successfully."
    redirect_to(sections_path(:page_id => @page.id))
  else
    render('new')
  end
end

...

private

def section_params
  params.require(:section).permit(:name, :position, :visible, :content_type, :content)
  end

def find_page
  @page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
end

def set_section_count
 @section_count = @page.sections.count
  if params[:action] == 'new' || params[:action] == 'create'
   @section_count += 1
  end
end
```

with error originating from line in 'create':

```
if @section.save
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 root :to => 'public#index'

 get 'show/:permalink', :to => 'public#show', :as => 'public_show'

 get 'admin', :to => 'access#menu'
 get 'access/menu'
 get 'access/login'
 post 'access/attempt_login'
 get 'access/logout'

 resources :admin_users, :except => [:show] do
   member do
    get :delete
   end
 end

 resources :subjects do
   member do
    get :delete
   end
 end

 resources :pages do
   member do
    get :delete
   end
 end

 resources :sections do
   member do
    get :delete
   end
 end
```

section.rb

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord

 acts_as_list :scope => :subject

 belongs_to :page
 has_many :section_edits
 has_many :admin_users, :through => :section_edits

 scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
 scope :invisible, lambda { where(:visible => false) }
 scope :sorted, lambda { order("position ASC") }
 scope :newest_first, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }

 CONTENT_TYPES = ['text', 'HTML']

 validates_presence_of :name
 validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 255
 validates_inclusion_of :content_type, :in => CONTENT_TYPES,
 :message => "must be one of: #{CONTENT_TYPES.join(', ')}"
 validates_presence_of :content

end
```

page.rb

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord

 acts_as_list :scope => :subject

 belongs_to :subject, { :optional => false }
 has_many :sections
 has_and_belongs_to_many :admin_users

 scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
 scope :invisible, lambda { where(:visible => false) }
 scope :sorted, lambda { order("position ASC") }
 scope :newest_first, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }

 validates_presence_of :name
 validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 255
 validates_presence_of :permalink
 validates_length_of :permalink, :within => 3..255
 validates_uniqueness_of :permalink

end
```

subject.rb

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord

 acts_as_list

 has_many :pages

 scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
 scope :invisible, lambda { where(:visible => false) }
 scope :sorted, lambda { order("position ASC") }
 scope :newest_first, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }
 scope :search, lambda {|query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"]) }

 validates_presence_of :name
 validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 255

end
```

Rest of my code

https://github.com/danwernstrom13/simple_cms

Let me know if I can provide any more context or code... Your assistance greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove this line from `Section` model:

```
acts_as_list :scope => :subject
```

because `Section` does not belong to `Subject`.

This would be correct:

```
acts_as_list :scope => :page
```

Comment: AHHH... that was it!  Thanks, Oleksandr!

Comment: @DanielWernstrom Can you please mark answer as correct.